# Matrices and its product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices of A and B of order $m\times n$ and $n\times m$( need not be square matrices). If AB=I of order $m\times m$, then can we tell A and B are inverses to each other? Or we can tell only in the case of square matrices?

Please help me. I am confused about this.

Comment: Matrix inverses only exist for square matrices. However, for non-square matrices a thing as "generalized inverse" or "pseudo-inverse" do exist. But keep in mind you cannot call these "pure" inverses as with square matrices!

Comment: It depends on your definition. In our usual definition, the inverse is unique; since the 'inverse' in your case is not so, it may cause ambiguity. However, you can still informally say so or define an 'inverse set' consists of all the 'inverses', it's just that you cannot use the results which are only applicable to inverses under usual definition.

Comment: If $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m < n$, then the rank of $A$ (and thus the rank of both $AB$ and $BA$) will be at most $m$.  So, $BA$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose rank is **not** $n$.